# Save http.get respone in service variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

Imagine that you have a factory with a http.get request on initialization, like so:

```
app.factory('myService', function($http) {
   var someArray = [];

   $http.get('someUrl').then(function(response) {
        someArray = response.data; /* this does not work */
   }

   getSomeArray = function() {
       return someArray;
   }

   return {
      getSomeArray:getSomeArray
   }
}
```

How would you go about saving the respone.data in a correct way?

The reason I would like to know is that I'm assuming that the service is initialized before the controller so sending a promise to the controller would result in a callback to the service to save the variable, requiring an extra call.

Comment: Why you need to save response data in service variable?

Comment: I want to share the response data between two controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (and see in the docs), there is no way to initialize factory asynchronously. So it's not guaranteed that your response will be saved to the local variable before it is actually used by external call to `getSomeArray()`.

You should definitely use Promise for this: just trigger the request and save the promise:

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http) {

   var responsePromise = $http.get('someUrl').then(function (response) {
       return response.data;
   }

   return {
       getSomeArray: getSomeArray
   }


   function getSomeArray () {
       return responsePromise;
   }
}
```

---

```
myService.getSomeArray().then(function (someArray) {
    // ...
});
```